# Buildozer gives error at Lubuntu VM on W10

Tags: ubuntu, kivy, virtual-machine, kivy-language

I am a freshman at Kivy and I'm trying to learn it. I am currently running Lubuntu on a VM hosted by a W10 machine.

I found some codes from internet and I want to use them on my own  phone. So I used Buildozer (ver 0.37). At first I was facing with error about the Buildozer were trying to download an outdated version of Android NDK but it was so outdated the link was no longer valid.

So first I downloaded the NDK from  my browser and extracted it to required directory, then I edited `Android.py` at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets` to ensure that the Buildozer see my NDK. Buildozer sees my NDK right now but it gives errors.

Here they are:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1059, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 92, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 102, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 176, in prepare_for_build
    self.target.install_platform()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 507, in install_platform
    self._install_android_ndk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 285, in _install_android_ndk
    _version = re.search('(.+?)[a-z]', self.android_ndk_version).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: Could you try using the buildozer master branch on github? I've just updated it and it should be working properly.

Comment: For anybody who faces with similar problems ı have downloaded 9c version from another source and extracted to '/home/<username>/.buildozer/android/platform' that seems to solve my problem

Comment: @inclement  after cloning the master branch with git clone and re-trying everything i faced with segmentation fault (core dumped) 
make: *** [Makefile:426: sharedmods] Error 139